# List getting duplicated from Firestore Collections

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

currently I'm trying to get document from a collection on firestore, each time I add a document on my application, the list gets duplicated on my application yet I'm only viewing an ID for that document in the firestore collection...

Here's my code for add data to the collection:-

```js
import Sidebar from './../../components/sidebar/Sidebar';
import Navbar from './../../components/navbar/Navbar';
import "./new.scss"

import { useState } from 'react';
import DriveFolderUploadIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DriveFolderUpload';
import { addDoc, collection, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { db } from '../../firebase';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';



const New = ({inputs}) => {

  const [file, setFile] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const navigate = useNavigate();


  const handleInput = (e) =>{
    const id = e.target.id;
    const value = e.target.value

    setData({...data, [id]:value});
  }

  const handleAdd = async(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Add a new document in collection "cities"
      await addDoc(collection(db, "clients"), {
        ...data,
        timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
      });
      navigate("/users")
  }



  return (
    <div className='new'>
    <Sidebar/>
    <div className="newContainer">
    <Navbar/>
    <div className="top">
    <h1>Add New Client</h1>
    </div>
    <div className="bottom">
    <div className="left">
      <img src={file ? URL.createObjectURL(file): "https://icon-library.com/images/no-image-icon/no-image-icon-0.jpg"} alt=''/>
    </div>
    <div className="right">
    
    <form onSubmit={handleAdd}>
              <div className="formInput">
                <label htmlFor="file">
                  Image: <DriveFolderUploadIcon className="icon" />
                </label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  id="file"
                  onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
                  style={{ display: "none" }}
                />
              </div>

              {inputs.map((input) => (
                <div className="formInput" key={input.id}>
                  <label>{input.label}</label>
                  <input
                    id={input.id}
                    type={input.type}
                    placeholder={input.placeholder}
                    onChange={handleInput}
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
              <button type="submit">
                Send
              </button>
            </form>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default New
```

Here's also the code where I'm fetching the data from the collection:-

```js
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import "./datatable.scss";
import { userColumns } from "../../datatablesource";
import VisibilityIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Visibility';
import EditNoteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EditNote';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Tooltip } from "@mui/material";

import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { doc, deleteDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import {db} from "../../firebase"
  
const Datatable = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  let list = []
  useEffect(() =>{
    const fetchData = async () =>{
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "clients"));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        list.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data()})
});
    setData(list);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])

  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    try {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "clients", id));
      setData(data.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };



const actionColumn = [
  { field: "action", headerName: "Action", width: 150, renderCell:(params)=>{
    return (
      <div className="cellAction">

        <Link>
        <Tooltip title="View Client" placement="bottom">
        <div className="viewButton"><VisibilityIcon/></div>
        </Tooltip>
        </Link>

        <Link>
        <Tooltip title="Edit Client" placement="bottom">
        <div className="editButton"><EditNoteIcon/></div>
        </Tooltip>
        </Link>


        <Link>
        <Tooltip title="Delete Client" placement="bottom">
        <div className="deleteButton"  onClick={() => handleDelete(params.row.id)}><DeleteIcon/></div>
        </Tooltip>
        </Link>
        
      </div>
    )
  }}
]
  return (
        <div className="datatable">
            <div className="datatableTitle">
        Add New Client
        <Link to="/users/new" className="link">
          Add New
        </Link>
      </div>
      <DataGrid
        className="datagrid"
        rows={data}
        columns={userColumns.concat(actionColumn)}
        pageSize={9}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[9]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Datatable
```

Yet it's still getting duplicated on my list, can anyone assist me on this??

Answer (score 1):

Move the `list` inside the fetchData function:

```
  let list = []; // <-- NOT HERE!

  useEffect(() =>{
    const fetchData = async () =>{
      let list = []; // <-- MOVE HERE
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "clients"));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        list.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data()})
      });
      setData(list);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])
```

In React v18, the Component will render twice (in ReactStrict mode). The `list` outside the `fetchData` creates a closure and appends (push) the data twice.

---

Sidenote: If you need to append to the `data` state variable, then use the callback version of the state setter:

```
setData( prevData => /* Do something with prevData and list */ );
```

Comment: It worked still, but I listened in real time. Thanks